# TP link подружить локальные сети двух роутеров

Tags: маршрутизация, маршрутизатор

Есть такая схема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И проблема, как из ПК (р1) пропинговать ПК подключённые к роутер#2? Но если пинговать с машин которые подключены к роутеру2, машины подключённые к роутер#1,то все нормально пингуется...

Все это дело подключено по пороводу

Роутеры самые простые за 2к рублей

Comment: Выткните провод WAN из роутер2 в роутер1 - надо соединять их LAN-LAN

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar все лан порты на роутере 2 заняты заняты...

Comment: купите за 500 ре простенький хаб на пару портов

Comment: и с адресами разберитесь, надо чтобы они были в одной подсети, а то у вас в одном 192.168.0.1 а в другом 192.168.1.1 и маска видимо стоит 255.255.255.0 - либо расширяйте маску либо меняйте адреса

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar я пробовал им ставить один ип и  одну сеть , выдаёт сообщение о конфликте...

Comment: Ну конечно нельзя ставить одинаковые адреса :) Один ставьте например 192.168.0.1, а второй 192.168.0.2 и таблицу DHCP начинайте с номера 192.168.0.3 - тогда не будет конфликта и пропишите в обоих роутерах статические адреса друг-друга

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar статические адреса друг друга? Это как?

Comment: В стандартной для TP-Link конфигурации роутера работает так: `Network->DHCP Server->Advanced->Address reservation` и заполняете таблицу `Mac Address -> Reserved IP address`

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar а как их подружить в одну сеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Роутер 2 маскирует внутренние запросы своим адресом. А входящие адреса во внутрь своей сети не принимает.

Если вам не нужны две разных сети, отключите в роутере 2 DHCP. Все будут в одной сети. Роутер 2 будет служить как свитч. Провод из WAN контакта надо убрать в LAN. Свитч работает только с LAN контактами.

DHCP
Настройки DHCP
DHCP-сервер Отключить
Firewall Отключить
DNS Отключить

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109214/discussion-on-answer-by-alexglebe-tp-link-----).